# In ajax how to hide one div and display sucess in next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax for search by onkeyup. I want to display all result if textbox is empty but if textbox is not empty then display according to typed text.

`<input type="text" onkeyup="searchme()" id="search_id"  />`

```
   function searchme() {
        var value;
        value = document.getElementById('search_id').value;
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_projectList.php",
            data: {value: value,
            'table': 'revenue'},
            success: function (result)
            {$("#resultDiv").html(result); } })
    }
```

I want to show .resultDiv id and hide previously shown result 
`<div id="resultDiv"></div>`
 get_projectList.php contain query for result

Thanks In Advance

Comment: `result` should have all the values if `text` is empty..

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the problem, and explicitly state what problem you have. Does your computer explode when running this code, do you get an error, do you just get the wrong displayed html? If so, what error or what output do you get?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I mention more script for detail

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchme() {
    var value;
    value = document.getElementById('search_id').value;
    if(value.length > 0 )
    {

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_projectList.php",
        data: {value: value,
        'table': 'revenue'},
        success: function (result)
        {
         $("#project_all").hide();
         $("#resultDiv").html(result); 

       } })
       }
       else {$("#project_all").show(); }

}


<input type="text" id="search_id" onkeyup="searchme(this)">

 <div id="project_all">  // on page load
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
 </div>
  <div id="resultDiv">

  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/medashiva/e3xvorqg/1/)

hope helps :)

Why you are adding ajax results to resultDiv just add results to project_all div only.

still getting issue , let me know.. :)

Comment: it works bcz for every time you are doing $("#resultDiv").html(result) this, so it will removes the old results and shows the new results.. :)

Comment: At the beginning when page is loaded, textbox is empty and shows all result. when user inputs text it have to show results according to inserted text

Answer (score 0):

In the success first make the html empty and add your success result.

```js
function searchme() {
  var value;
  value = document.getElementById('search_id').value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_projectList.php",
    data: {value: value,
    'table': 'revenue'},
     success: function (result)
     {
       $("#project_all").hide()
       $("#resultDiv").show();
       $("#resultDiv").html(); /* works even thisline is excluded */
       $("#resultDiv").html(result); 
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you returning the required date from the result?

Comment: Okay you are getting data, but you need to hide a div? What is the div you wanna hide?

Comment: `<div id="resultDiv"></div>` div should shown after event
  `<div id="project_all">` this div is show at the beginning bt after event occurs it should be hidden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104854/discussion-between-sravan-and-mr-shrestha).